# no puedo insertar los datos de un formulario en una tabla de una base de datos usando PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo un formulario en html y mi código PHP en un archivo aparte, siento que he seguido todas las indicaciones y no entiendo, pero los datos no se cargan en la tabla de la base de datos, adjunto foto de la base de datos, Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

```
<?php

$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost","id19281767_neviero_db", "Camila1983.*", 
"id19281767_naviero_db");
if (!$conectar){
echo 'Error al conectar a la base de datos';
}
include_once ('conexion.php');

$host ="localhost";
$user ="id19281767_neviero_db";
$pass ="Camila1983.*";
$db="id19281767_naviero_db";

$conexion = mysqli_connect ($host,$user,$pass,$db)or die("Problemas al Conectar");
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$db)or die("problemas al conectar con la base de datos");

$IdSolicitud=$_POST["IdSolicitud"];     
$documento=$_POST["documento"];     
$NomCliente=$_POST["NomCliente"];       
$empresa=$_POST["empresa"];     
$correo=$_POST["correo"];       
$DirCliente=$_POST["DirCliente"];       
$Ciudad=$_POST["Ciudad"];       
$TelCliente=$_POST["TelCliente"];       
$TipoSolicitud=$_POST["TipoSolicitud"];     
$Equipo=$_POST["Equipo"];       
$FechaSolicitud=$_POST["FechaSolicitud"];       
$HoraSolicitud=$_POST["HoraSolicitud"];     
$diagnostico=$_POST["diagnostico"];     
$idTecnico=$_POST["idTecnico"];     
$NomTecnico=$_POST["NomTecnico"];       
$TelTecnico=$_POST["TelTecnico"];

    $insertar = "INSERT INTO solicitud (IdSolicitud,    documento,  NomCliente, empresa,     
    correo, DirCliente, Ciudad, TelCliente, TipoSolicitud,  Equipo, FechaSolicitud,  
    HoraSolicitud, diagnostico, idTecnico,  NomTecnico, TelTecnico) value 
     ('$IdSolicitud','$documento','$NomCliente','$empresa','$correo','$DirCliente','$Ciudad',
       '$TelCliente','$TipoSolicitud','$Equipo',
       '$FechaSolicitud','$HoraSolicitud','$diagnostico',
        '$idTecnico','$NomTecnico','$TelTecnico')";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);

```
     if (!$resultado) {
      echo 'Error';
     } else {
      echo "solicitud registrada con exito <br> <a href=orden.php'>Volver</a>";
     }
      //cerrar conexion
     mysqli_close($conexion);
     ?>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué te estás conectando dos veces al servidor? Si es un error deberías eliminar y quedarte con una sola conexión. Tenés algún mensaje de error que lance Php o Mysql?

Comment: cuando compruebas el $resultado, en lugar de hacer un echo de la cadena error, llama a `mysqli_error($link)`, para que te muestre si ha habido algun error. Pero como te dice @Dreyf, tienes dos conexiones, puedes tener problemas con eso tambien.

Comment: En tu sentencia SQL debe ser `values`, en plural.